# How to create and link a rundeck-config.properties in Rundeck

Tags: yaml, devops, rundeck, configmap, pagerduty

So first of all Here is my Setup.
I deployed Rundeck on EKS using two YAML files, `rundeck-svc.yaml , rundeck-deployment.yaml`
Those can be found here [text](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/howto/how2-terra-rd-eks.html)

Now I wanted to do two things

1. first of all change the default username and password from admin, admin to something else.
2. Connect Rundeck to some sort of permanent storage so that it could persist data.

Both of these things require to save configs in `rundeck-config.properties` as below->
1.

```
rundeck.password.reset.enabled=true
```

2. 

```
dataSource.driverClassName = org.postgresql.Driver
dataSource.url = jdbc:postgresql://pgsql.rundeck.local/rundeck
dataSource.username = rundeckuser
dataSource.password = rundeckpassword
```

**So with having those two yaml files only how do I create a `rundeck-config.properties` file and link that up with rundeck Deployment file correctly.**

Here is my exact rundeck-deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: rundeck
  labels:
    env: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      env: dev
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        env: dev
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: rundeck-svc-account
      containers:
        - name: rundeck
          image: rundeck/rundeck:4.8.0
          env:
            - name: RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED
              value: "true"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4440
```

I would be highly grateful if you could provide some exact template on how to create a config and link a config file.

I tried googling around, but could not find some exact resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a `rundeck-config.properties` file, the Rundeck container has been designed to use the container environment variables that you can use in your Kubernetes deployment file. These environment variables are equal to the `rundeck-config.properties` file parameters, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/docker.html#environment-variables), and [this](https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/blob/master/kubernetes/rundeckpro-deployment.yaml).

In a few words, the file is present in the container, and using the environment variables you can add/override the file parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I did the setup, and got my rundeck to store project, nodes, and other data in PostrgesQL, but still, it looses all the installed plugins like Kubernetes plugin on restart, which hinders with proper functioning of the project.